# Visual Studio C# ODBC Sharepoint connector Read Only Field Error

Tags: c#, sharepoint, odbc, sharepoint-online

I keep getting the following error from the ODBC Sharepoint connector when trying to update a dataset to Sharepoint Online:

```
ERROR [HY000] Column [ID] could not be updated. This column is read-only.'
```

I'm actually not trying to update the ID field, but the code created by Visual Studio wants to update the entire row in the `DataGridView`, including read only fields like the `ID` field.  Whenever `TableAdapter.Update(DataSet)` is called I get errors on the read only fields.  I'm happy to ignore the read only fields entirely but I can't find the code, or any settings, that allow me to do this. Thank you!

Comment: SharePoint isn't a database. Lists and document libraries aren't tables. What ODBC driver are you talking about and what are you actually trying to do? Visual Studio doesn't update anything  - the code does. The statements executed are controlled by the DataTable, TableAdapter or DataAdapter configuration. What does your code actually do?

Comment: Since SharePoint isn't a database, and TableAdapter was built to work with databases, you can't expect it to know what can or can't be updated. It will generate statements the same way it would for a database. If some field is declared as `Identity` or database-generated, it won't try to update it. Do, how is the DataTable configured? What is its schema?

Comment: My code is negligible.  I'm relying on the code generated by Visual Studio in TableAdapter.Update() to update changes made to a DataGridView table being filled by a Sharepoint list.  The ODBC connector is Microsoft's Sharepoint ODBC Driver.  It gives the error.  What I am missing is where and how do I tell the code, generated by Visual Studio, not to update those columns that are system generated.  Where are they declared/configured?

Comment: Again, what SharePoint ODBC Driver are you talking about? Googling for this produces nothing. Only CData produces [an ODBC driver](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CDATASOFTWARE.SharePointODBCDriver) that tries to work with SharePoint libraries and lists as if they were tables

Comment: `My code is negligible.` that's what's throwing errors though. You're using some unkown ODBC driver to connect to something that isn't a database and try to update data through that unknonw driver, instead of the built-in server or client APIs. Post your code, the actual ODBC version you use, preferably with a link to the download page

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue in the following code under the dataset designer.  I commented out the old code and made a much simpler statement:

this._adapter.UpdateCommand.Connection = this.Connection;
            //this._adapter.UpdateCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE \"SOAP\".\"Work Order Test Import\" SET \"ID\" = ?, \"Label setting\" = ?, \"Label " +
            //    "setting_ID\" = ?, \"Retention label\" = ?, \"Retention label_ID\" = ?, \"Label applied" +
            //    " by\" = ?, \"Label applied by_ID\" = ?, \"Retention label Applied\" = ?, \"Retention l" +
            //    "abel Applied_ID\" = ?, \"Item is a Record\" = ?, \"Version\" = ?, \"Affected User(s)\" " +
            //    "= ?, \"App Created By\" = ?, \"App Created By_ID\" = ?, \"App Modified By\" = ?, \"App " +
            //    "Modified By_ID\" = ?, \"Assigned To\" = ?, \"Assigned To_ID\" = ?, \"Attachments\" = ?," +
            //    " \"Created By\" = ?, \"Created By_ID\" = ?, \"Compliance Asset Id\" = ?, \"Computer ID\"" +
            //    " = ?, \"Contact Info\" = ?, \"Content Type\" = ?, \"Created\" = ?, \"Department\" = ?, \"" +
            //    "Desired Due Date\" = ?, \"Detailed Description\" = ?, \"Type\" = ?, \"Edit\" = ?, \"Modi" +
            //    "fied By\" = ?, \"Modified By_ID\" = ?, \"Folder Child Count\" = ?, \"Folder Child Coun" +
            //    "t_ID\" = ?, \"Item Child Count\" = ?, \"Item Child Count_ID\" = ?, \"Location\" = ?, \"L" +
            //    "ocation_ID\" = ?, \"Modified\" = ?, \"Notes\" = ?, \"Priority\" = ?, \"Reason On Hold\" =" +
            //    " ?, \"Resolution\" = ?, \"Reason Cancelled\" = ?, \"Status\" = ?, \"Submitted by\" = ?, " +
            //    "\"Submitted by_ID\" = ?, \"Title\" = ? WHERE ((\"ID\" = ?) AND ((? = 1 AND \"Label sett" +
            //    "ing\" IS NULL) OR (\"Label setting\" = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND \"Label setting_ID\" IS NU" +
            //    "LL) OR (\"Label setting_ID\" = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND \"Retention label\" IS NULL) OR (" +
            //    "\"Retention label\" = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND \"Retention label_ID\" IS NULL) OR (\"Reten" +
            //    "tion label_ID\" = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND \"Label applied by\" IS NULL) OR (\"Label appl" +
            //    "ied by\" = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND \"Label applied by_ID\" IS NULL) OR (\"Label applied " +
            //    "by_ID\" = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND \"Retention label Applied\" IS NULL) OR (\"Retention l" +
            //    "abel Applied\" = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND \"Retention label Applied_ID\" IS NULL) OR (\"R" +
            //    "etention label Applied_ID\" = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND \"Item is a Record\" IS NULL) OR " +
            //    "(\"Item is a Record\" = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND \"Version\" IS NULL) OR (\"Version\" = ?))" +
            //    " AND ((? = 1 AND \"Affected User(s)\" IS NULL) OR (\"Affected User(s)\" = ?)) AND ((" +
            //    "? = 1 AND \"App Created By\" IS NULL) OR (\"App Created By\" = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND \"" +
            //    "App Created By_ID\" IS NULL) OR (\"App Created By_ID\" = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND \"App M" +
            //    "odified By\" IS NULL) OR (\"App Modified By\" = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND \"App Modified B" +
            //    "y_ID\" IS NULL) OR (\"App Modified By_ID\" = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND \"Assigned To\" IS N" +
            //    "ULL) OR (\"Assigned To\" = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND \"Assigned To_ID\" IS NULL) OR (\"Assi" +
            //    "gned To_ID\" = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND \"Attachments\" IS NULL) OR (\"Attachments\" = ?))" +
            //    " AND ((? = 1 AND \"Created By\" IS NULL) OR (\"Created By\" = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND \"C" +
            //    "reated By_ID\" IS NULL) OR (\"Created By_ID\" = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND \"Compliance Ass" +
            //    "et Id\" IS NULL) OR (\"Compliance Asset Id\" = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND \"Computer ID\" IS" +
            //    " NULL) OR (\"Computer ID\" = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND \"Contact Info\" IS NULL) OR (\"Cont" +
            //    "act Info\" = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND \"Content Type\" IS NULL) OR (\"Content Type\" = ?))" +
            //    " AND ((? = 1 AND \"Created\" IS NULL) OR (\"Created\" = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND \"Departm" +
            //    "ent\" IS NULL) OR (\"Department\" = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND \"Desired Due Date\" IS NULL)" +
            //    " OR (\"Desired Due Date\" = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND \"Detailed Description\" IS NULL) OR" +
            //    " (\"Detailed Description\" = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND \"Type\" IS NULL) OR (\"Type\" = ?)) " +
            //    "AND ((? = 1 AND \"Edit\" IS NULL) OR (\"Edit\" = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND \"Modified By\" I" +
            //    "S NULL) OR (\"Modified By\" = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND \"Modified By_ID\" IS NULL) OR (\"M" +
            //    "odified By_ID\" = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND \"Folder Child Count\" IS NULL) OR (\"Folder C" +
            //    "hild Count\" = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND \"Folder Child Count_ID\" IS NULL) OR (\"Folder C" +
            //    "hild Count_ID\" = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND \"Item Child Count\" IS NULL) OR (\"Item Child" +
            //    " Count\" = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND \"Item Child Count_ID\" IS NULL) OR (\"Item Child Cou" +
            //    "nt_ID\" = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND \"Location\" IS NULL) OR (\"Location\" = ?)) AND ((? = " +
            //    "1 AND \"Location_ID\" IS NULL) OR (\"Location_ID\" = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND \"Modified\" " +
            //    "IS NULL) OR (\"Modified\" = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND \"Notes\" IS NULL) OR (\"Notes\" = ?))" +
            //    " AND ((? = 1 AND \"Priority\" IS NULL) OR (\"Priority\" = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND \"Reaso" +
            //    "n On Hold\" IS NULL) OR (\"Reason On Hold\" = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND \"Resolution\" IS N" +
            //    "ULL) OR (\"Resolution\" = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND \"Reason Cancelled\" IS NULL) OR (\"Rea" +
            //    "son Cancelled\" = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND \"Status\" IS NULL) OR (\"Status\" = ?)) AND ((" +
            //    "? = 1 AND \"Submitted by\" IS NULL) OR (\"Submitted by\" = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND \"Subm" +
            //    "itted by_ID\" IS NULL) OR (\"Submitted by_ID\" = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND \"Title\" IS NUL" +
            //    "L) OR (\"Title\" = ?)))";
            this._adapter.UpdateCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE \"SOAP\".\"Work Order Test Import\" SET \"Detailed Description\"=?, \"Title\"=?, \"Assigned To_ID\"=?, \"Status\"=?, \"Affected User(s)\"=?, \"Resolution\"=?, \"Location_ID\"= ?, \"Submitted by_ID\"=?, \"Department\"=?, \"Computer ID\"=?, \"Contact Info\"=?, \"Notes\"=?, \"Priority\"=? WHERE (\"ID\" = @ID)";
            this._adapter.UpdateCommand.CommandType = global::System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            this._adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.Odbc.OdbcParameter("Detailed_Description", global::System.Data.Odbc.OdbcType.NVarChar, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, ((byte)(0)), ((byte)(0)), "Detailed Description", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null));
            this._adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.Odbc.OdbcParameter("Title", global::System.Data.Odbc.OdbcType.NVarChar, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, ((byte)(0)), ((byte)(0)), "Title", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null));
            this._adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.Odbc.OdbcParameter("Assigned_To_ID", global::System.Data.Odbc.OdbcType.Int, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, ((byte)(0)), ((byte)(0)), "Assigned To_ID", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null));
            this._adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.Odbc.OdbcParameter("Status", global::System.Data.Odbc.OdbcType.NVarChar, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, ((byte)(0)), ((byte)(0)), "Status", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null));
            this._adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.Odbc.OdbcParameter("Affected_User(s)", global::System.Data.Odbc.OdbcType.NVarChar, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, ((byte)(0)), ((byte)(0)), "Affected User(s)", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null));
            this._adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.Odbc.OdbcParameter("Resolution", global::System.Data.Odbc.OdbcType.NVarChar, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, ((byte)(0)), ((byte)(0)), "Resolution", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null));
            this._adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.Odbc.OdbcParameter("Location_ID", global::System.Data.Odbc.OdbcType.Int, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, ((byte)(0)), ((byte)(0)), "Location_ID", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null));
            this._adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.Odbc.OdbcParameter("Submitted_by_ID", global::System.Data.Odbc.OdbcType.Int, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, ((byte)(0)), ((byte)(0)), "Submitted by_ID", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null));
            this._adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.Odbc.OdbcParameter("Department", global::System.Data.Odbc.OdbcType.NVarChar, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, ((byte)(0)), ((byte)(0)), "Department", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null));
            this._adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.Odbc.OdbcParameter("Computer_ID", global::System.Data.Odbc.OdbcType.NVarChar, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, ((byte)(0)), ((byte)(0)), "Computer ID", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null));
            this._adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.Odbc.OdbcParameter("Contact_Info", global::System.Data.Odbc.OdbcType.NVarChar, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, ((byte)(0)), ((byte)(0)), "Contact Info", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null));
            this._adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.Odbc.OdbcParameter("Notes", global::System.Data.Odbc.OdbcType.NVarChar, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, ((byte)(0)), ((byte)(0)), "Notes", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null));
            this._adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.Odbc.OdbcParameter("Priority", global::System.Data.Odbc.OdbcType.NVarChar, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, ((byte)(0)), ((byte)(0)), "Priority", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null));

```
        this._adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.Odbc.OdbcParameter("ID", global::System.Data.Odbc.OdbcType.Int, 0, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, ((byte)(0)), ((byte)(0)), "ID", global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null));
```